# Libreoffice / openoffice service proxy

Tags: performance, proxy, libreoffice

Our J2EE-based software is using Libreoffice headless services (usually located on another servers) to convert documents, supplying them via TCP/IP soffice port. Typical system may include up to 10 Libreoffice instances on 2-3 VMs to manage heavy load.

Long-living libreoffice headless instance have some issues in production:
1. It may freeze after converting severe number of documents.
2. It may freeze because of two simultaneous connection made to one instance.

It require special treatment and is quite hard to track all connections to libreoffice instances in threaded Java application. And its even more hard to test them for being hung and restart them, because they are intended to run as services on another server.

We spent much time to create special spooling code, but it is still far from solving the real issues in production.

Once I found a special piece of software acting as a proxy-server for Libreoffice instances. It open TCP/IP port and act like Libreoffice to any connecting party and connect to libreoffice instance by itself. It also tracks LO instances states and restart them if needed or after certain number of documents processed. However today I have spent all day searching for it and found nothing like this.

Is there any software acting as described proxy-server or maybe there is another approach which I should consider?